# How do a static library with Bitcode enabled withour error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang

I have error with lib.o [image]

I found a lot of answers to this question . I added -fembed-bitcode in other linker flags

[image]

and added -fembed-bitcode in other c flags

[image]

in project i added -fembed-bitcode too

[image]

But I still get this clang error.

Answer (score 2):

This actually looks like the lib your using was build without bitcode enabled. To fix this disable bitcode in buildSetting for your project.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHSWb.png[image]

Or get a version with bitcode enabled.